# Interface Polymorphism in C# 2.0

Tags: c#, .net, oop, interface, .net-2.0

Say I've got this interface:

```
public interface IFoo
{
   string Text {get;}
}
```

And this class that implements it:

```
public class Bar : IFoo
{
   public string Text
   {
      get {return "Hello World!";}
   }
}
```

I've got a function that takes as an argument a `List<IFoo>`.  When I try to pass it a `List<Bar>`, I get this compiler error:

```
Argument 1: cannot convert from System.Collections.Generic.List<Bar>
to System.Collections.Generic.List<IFoo>
```

Why is this?  It seems like that should work for the same reason as if I passed a list of a class that inherits from `Bar` directly.

Comment: Try using generics. Your function can then take List<T> as the argument. Check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564(v=vs.80).aspx Scroll down about half way to Generic methods

Comment: I need the objects passed to implement this interface, though.  If I were using a newer version of .NET, I would happily use generics and use `Func` parameters to get the info I needed out of the objects I pass.

Comment: According to the article I linked generics should work in .net 2.0

Comment: You *could* use `Frob(List<T> list) where T : IFoo`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Why is this? It seems like that should work for the same reason as if I passed a list of a class that inherits from Bar directly.

Because this disaster can happen:

```
class EvilBar : IFoo { }

List<Bar> list = new List<Bar>();
List<IFoo> foos = list; // suppose it were allowed
foos.Add(new EvilBar());
```

And now you've add an `EvilBar` to a list than can only accept `Bar`. Oops!

Basically, you've discovered that `T -> List<T>` is not covariant in `T`.

Comment: This doesn't seem like a problem though.  The compiler allowed the cast from `List<Bar>` to `List<IFoo>` because `Bar` implements `IFoo`.  For the same reason, it should allow adding an `EvilBar` to the list of objects that implement `IFoo`.  It should not, however, allow casting back from `List<IFoo>` to `List<Bar`.

Comment: Is this changed in later versions of .NET?

Comment: @Mr. Jefferson: No, you can not do such a reference conversion from `List<Bar>` to `List<IFoo>`. The object that would actually stand behind the reference is still a `List<Bar>` and it can't accept `EvilBar` even though a `List<IFoo>` could. It's fundamentally not possible.

Comment: Your evil example is totally irrelevant with this question. You can be evil even with simple polymorphism: `IFoo foo = new EvilBar();`.

Comment: @linepogl: What are you talking about? `IFoo foo = new EvilBar();` is perfectly fine. Did you downvote?

Comment: @Jason, exactly it is totally fine. And it is a direct analogy of you example which you have characterized as a disaster!

Comment: @linepogl: It is NOT a direct analogy. You can't add an `EvilBar` to a `List<Bar>`, and that is why my example is a disaster.

Comment: @linepogl I think what you're missing is that `list` and `foos` are still the same list.  When you use for example the .NET 3.5 extension method `Cast<T>` it's creating a new list, in which case it's fine to add anything to a `List<IFoo>` but in this case, since they're both the same list, adding `EvilBar` to `foos` looks fine on the surface, but it's actually still a `List<Bar>` which is not fine.

Comment: @Mr. Jefferson "The compiler allowed the cast from List<Bar> to List<IFoo> because Bar implements IFoo" is not a true statement.  In .NET 3.5 there's the `Cast<T>` extension method but it doesn't cast the list, it creates a new one (IEnumerable actually)  and casts all the members.  The list itself cannot be cast for the reasons @Jason mentioned.

Answer (score 4):

Because generic contravariance was not supported in .Net 2.0. You can do it with arrays though.

```
IFoo[] foos = new Bar[5];
```

Another option is to do

```
List<IFoo> myList = myBarList.ConvertAll(b => (IFoo)b);
```

Comment: That kind of covariance is broken, effectively for the reason outlined in my answer.

Comment: I converted my parameter to an array, added `.ToArray()` on the end of the argument passed, and the compiler is happy.

Comment: @Mr. Jefferson: It's not safe!

Comment: @Mr. Jefferson: Yes, you can run into runtime errors. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/10/17/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-part-two-array-covariance.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Do not pass `List<Bar>`. Use cast and pass this:

```
yourObj.YourMethod(yourListOfBar.Cast<IBar>().ToList());
```

Comment: I think your `Cast` method is not present in .NET 2.0.  Otherwise that would work great.